Series expansion of tensor w.r.t. parameter in xCoba
I am new to xAct, and I am using xCoba to do some calculations.
I have a metric as follows
<< xAct`xCoba`;

(*Manifold*)
DefManifold[M, 3, {\[Mu], \[Nu], \[Rho], \[Sigma], \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}];

(*t[]: Euclidean time; y[] radious direction; \[Phi][] angular direction*)
DefChart[nbtz, M, {0, 1, 2}, {t[], y[], \[Phi][]}, ChartColor -> Red];
(*Temperature*)
DefConstantSymbol[T, PrintAs -> "T"];
(*Angular momentum*)
DefConstantSymbol[J, PrintAs -> "J"];

DefScalarFunction[f1, PrintAs -> "f1"]; 
DefScalarFunction[f2, PrintAs -> "f2"];
DefScalarFunction[f3, PrintAs -> "f3"];
DefConstantSymbol[n, PrintAs -> "n"];
DefConstantSymbol[x, PrintAs -> "x"];

$Assumptions = n > 1 && T >= 0 && J > 0 ;

g0 = CTensor[
{{(y[]^2 - 1)/4 + 4 J^2 (-(I (y[] - 1))/(4 J))^2, 0, -I J (y[] - 1)},
 {0, 1/(4 (y[]^2 - 1)), 0},
 {-I J ( y[] - 1), 0, 4 J^2}},
{-nbtz, -nbtz}];(*Near Horizon BTZ metric*)

g1 = CTensor[(T/J)*
{{-(y[]^3 - 3 y[] + 2)/32 + J^2 y[] (-I (y[] - 1)/4/J)^2 + (y[] - 1) (y[]^2 - 1)/32, 0, J^2 y[] (y[] - 1) (-I/4/J) + J I (y[]^2 - 1)*6/32},
{0, (y[] + 2)/(32(y[] - 1)^2), 0},
{J^2 y[] (y[] - 1) (-I/4/J) + J I (y[]^2 - 1)*6/32, 0, J^2 y[]}},
{-nbtz, -nbtz}];(*1-order correction*)

g = g0 + g1;

SetCMetric[g0, nbtz, SignatureOfMetric -> {2, 1, 0}];
cd = CovDOfMetric[g] // FullSimplify;
rt = Riemann[cd] // FullSimplify;
rc = Ricci[cd] // FullSimplify;
rcs = RicciScalar[cd] // FullSimplify;

What I want to do:
Expand cd, rt, rc and rcs to $\mathcal{O}(T)$ since I want to calculate the first order $T$ corrections to
$$
h_{\mu\nu}(\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}\nabla^2-\frac{1}{4}g^{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}\nabla^2-\frac{2}{3}R^{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}+R^{\mu\rho\nu\sigma}+\frac{1}{9}g^{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}R)h_{\rho\sigma}
$$
where $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor which is independent from $T$.
What I tried:
I have used something like Series[rcs, {T, 0, 1}] and Also Series[rcs[], {T, 0, 1}]. And none of these worked. Doing such thing component by component is OK but I will do all of these things in 10-dimension again, and it will be a disaster then.So may I ask are there any quick ways to do this?
By the way, the calculation of cd[-\[Gamma]]@cd[\[Gamma]]@h[-\[Mu],-\[Nu]] is very slow, which is performance bottleneck of my code. Is there any quick way to do that (note that in 10-dimension it will be slower)
Thank you in advance for your help.
